# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My spring boot application communicate to a remote https url and it gives the above mentioned error while hitting a POST request.
I went through multiple stackoverflow posts for the same topic.
Installed/imported required certificates using keytool and restarted JVM. But that didn't resolve my issue. The error message is the same, however the root cause is different here apart from importing certs. Just wanted to post this as new question since I have been trying for last couple of days without any luck what so ever!

Comment: You are sure you have imported the correct certificate including the certificate chain?

Comment: While you claim that you *"... went through multiple stackoverflow posts for the same topic... "* and installed any necessary certificates your question does not provide enough details so that others can fully understand your issue and reproduce it - all one could do is to speculate how your code might look like and what you might have done wrong or if something is wrong with the server etc. Please provide the necessary information by following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a `spring boot` related issue. I figured out the issue was with JDK. Default Oracle version installed in the system added wrong JRE path to environment variable. I have pointed it to correct JDK version and imported certs there. That resolved the issue. Thank you @Jens for the helpful input.